# Type Mismatch, Run Time error 13

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a type mismatch error for the below at the if iRowValue null check

what i am trying to do is to determine if the value already exists in the sheet then update that column or else append at the end.

```
Public iRowValue As Long

Public iRow As Long

----------

Private Sub Update_Click()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim FindString1 as String


With ws.Range("A:A")
         Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString1, _
                         After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                         LookIn:=xlValues, _
                         LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                         SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                         MatchCase:=False)

         If Rng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Name does not Exists"
         Else
            iRowValue = Rng.Row
         End If
    End With

**If iRowValue <> "" Then**

iRow = iRowValue

Else

iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
  .End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
End If

ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.FirstName.Value

ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.LastCode.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iRowValue is declared as Long, you then try to compare it to a String - which can't work. Simply compare against 0 and it should work.